# JQuery Message with Asp.NET code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Don't have much knowledge on JQuery/CSS and would be helpful if someone could help me here.

The idea is to show a client side message box using JQuery while grabbing some data from code behind. The data from server is dynamic and will be assigned to the function parameter on button click in code behind.

**Issue:** It is working as expected only once. Second time onwards, I am able to see the message pops up but no contents ( anything I defined within message div)

Script:

```js
function ShowPopup(message) {
             $(function () {
                 $("#dialog").dialog({
                              height: 400,
                              width: 500,
                              modal: true,
                              position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+350' },
                              title: message,
                              buttons: {
                                  Close: function () {
                                      $(this).dialog("close");
                                                                          
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      );
                  });
              };
```

Html:

```html
  <div id="dialog" class="ui-helper-hidden">        
    <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" >Proin elit arcu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Rutrum commodo</a></li>
    
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void BtnMoreInfo_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "Message from server side";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where your BtnMoreInfo_OnClick event is being triggered.  Wouldn't a better approach be to use a JavaScript click event to trigger the dialog, which then also does an AJAX call to a WebMethod in your code behind?  This would prevent reliance on a postback (i.e.  it's faster and skips all the page lifecycle nonsense)

Comment: I have a grid view (asp.net), which has a template column. This template column has a single button. This idea is to provide more information on a specific record than loading it in DOM. The data is hell of string, which I don't want to load when page load. Idea was to load on demand text content upon clicking that button. Sorry I am very poor at web related and not my cup of coffee. But has to address a fix on urgent basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turnout to be a duplicating Div, which was part of master page. Mentioning unique name solved this issue. Sorry being an ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

can you please use the dialog code inside a button click, and i assume your request was not Jquery AJax. 
so on page load/or Dynamically after page Load place our message in HTML DOM and take that message on button click, something like this,

```
    $(function () {
    $('.yourButton').click(function () {
        var message = $('#messageDiv').attr('data-message');
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            height: 400,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            position: {my: 'top', at: 'top+350'},
            title: message,
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                }
            }
        }
        );
    });
});
```

then place your message in html DOM, i prefer it as data attribute.

**html**

```
<div id="messageDiv" data-message="yourMessage"></div>
```

thank you and let me know if it works as expected.

Comment: I have a grid view (asp.net), which has a template column. This template column has a single button (execute at server). This means for every row in grid will has a button called 'MoreInfo'. The is to load data on demand upon clicking that button. So your approach won't work in my scenario. Thanks anyway.

Comment: are you using Jquery Ajax to fetch data from server.? if yes do the dialog open code in your ajax success

Comment: No. MS ScriptManager and UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have **ScriptManager** in your page, you can create a function in C# code, and then call this function each time you want to show the message. This is my example:

```
protected void Message(string str)
{
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  stringBuilder.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
  stringBuilder.Append("window.onload=function(){");
  stringBuilder.Append("alert('");
  stringBuilder.Append(str);
  stringBuilder.Append("')};");
  stringBuilder.Append("</script>");
  this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", stringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Sorry. I do have a script manager since the page has other parts, which does partial rendering.